# API Supports DELETE on one model, but not another

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api

I have scaffolded DELETE methods for two objects. Currently, the users object can accept a DELETE request and works fine, but the requests object gives me the below message:

```
{
"Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'DELETE'."
}
```

The User code and call is:

```
// DELETE: api/Users/5
        [Route("{id}"), ResponseType(typeof(User))]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteUser(string id)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.Users.Remove(user);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(user);
        }

http://localhost:8080/api/users/2
content-type: application/json
DELETE
```

The request code and call is below:

```
// DELETE: api/ServiceRequests/5
        [Route("{id}:int"), ResponseType(typeof(ServiceRequest))]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteServiceRequest(int id)
        {
            ServiceRequest serviceRequest = db.ServiceRequests.Find(id);
            if (serviceRequest == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.ServiceRequests.Remove(serviceRequest);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(serviceRequest);
        }


http://localhost:8080/api/servicerequests/2
content-type: application/json
DELETE
```

Oddly enough, if I change the `Route("{id}:int")` to `Route("{id}")`, it functions fine, but eliminates my integer constraint.

How do I allow access to DELETE for the service requests?

Comment: Have you tried using the `[HttpDelete]` attribute above your `DeleteServiceRequest` method?

Comment: @RonSaylor I have, and it does not affect. However, oddly enough, if I change Route("{id}:int") to Route("{id}") it works fine.... I'm editing the post to include this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route attribute syntax is wrong, it should be:

```
[Route("{id:int}"), ResponseType(typeof(ServiceRequest))]
```

The route constraints should be inside the `{}`